# I want to generate ramdom numbers account to the number of players get as input

Tags: python

I'm creating a dice game in python:)

I got the number of plays as input like this

```
no_of players = int(input('Number od players: '))
```

How can I generate random numbers 1,6 according to the number of players?

Comment: If you want `n` (where n is no of players) random numbers, you can look into `random,sample()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Random number generator that generates random numbers between 1 and 6

```
import random

print(random.randint(1, 6))
```